# Simple newsletter module is not able to send

Tags: emails

My drupal website are using [simple newsletter](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module.
I successfully recieve email from the module that I used my @hotmail.com to subscribe.

But I use other domain email such as @testdomain.com to subscribe, I cannot receive any email that send from the module.

Any solution or other free newsletter module to use?
Thank you.